# GtkTreeviewColumn with different combo model for each row

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, gtktreeview

I have a global set of values, e.g. `["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Quux"]`. Each row in my `TreeView` represents an entity that can only deal with a subset of these values. For example, the first row might deal with `"Foo"` and `"Bar"`, and the second, `"Bar"` and `"Quux"`. I want a `ComboBox` column to allow each row to select one of the values it can deal with.

However, from the code I have now, the entire column can only have one model for the `ComboBox`:

```
crc = gtk.CellRendererCombo()
crc.set_property('model', fooValuesModel)
crc.set_property('text-column', 0)
crc.set_property('editable', True)
crc.set_property('has_entry', False)

cl = gtk.TreeViewColumn(ctitle, crc, text=i)
treeView.append_column(cl)
```

I have only one opportunity to set a model for the entire column. Is there any way to have different stores for each row, or to filter values somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also another way to do this.

See also:
http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-perl-list/2005-July/msg00065.html

(It's in perl, but shouldn't be too difficult to convert to python)

The secret being this:

Say you have a TreeView using a TreeStore as its model. And one of the columns uses a combobox cell renderer which will get a ListStore model per row:

1. You can put ListStores into TreeStore columns, in perl that would be a column of type `Gtk2::ListStore`. Of course you wouldn't add a column to the TreeView displaying this directly. Instead:
2. You can have the comboboxcell-column use that column from the Treeview as its ListStore when you add it to the treeview, using 'insert_column_with_attributes' and connecting the 'model' attribute to the ListStore column of the TreeStore.
3. When you add a row to the treeview, just put a complete ListStore into the ListStore column of the TreeStore. You can then fill the per-row ListStore with whatever values you want.

Comment: ah makes a lot of sense! seems like the best solution yet

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [`gtk.TreeModelFilter`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreemodelfilter.html). It is a tree model containing filtered values of another underlying tree model. You can decide which rows should be visible by calling `set_visible_func()` on the filtered model.

Comment: How to trigger the model change? Anything better than `cursor-changed` on the `TreeView`?

Comment: @bobince, unfortunately not as far as I can think of. You can call `refilter()` on the model whenever you want to change it but I think `cursor-changed` is the best option as to which signal handler to do that in.